# Javascript Button called on start and not after

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Javascript-Code is called on start instead when the button is pressed. Similar questions didn't solve my problem.

```
<button type="button" onclick="anzeigen()">Notizen anzeigen</button>
```

I tried "anzeigen()" also without quotes, but it didn't help either.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            function anzeigen() {
            $("#ausgabe").empty();
            <% System.out.println("test");%>
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/Notizblock/rest/" +     
                    "notizblock/notizen",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {

                        $.each(data, function(i, data1) {      
                            // Erstellt neues Element      
                            var p = $("<p>");      
                            // Zugriff aus JSON - Objekt      
                            p.append(data1.nnummer + " " + data1.tnummer);      
                            $("#ausgabe").append(p);     
                            });

                    }
                });
            };
        });
</script>
```

No matter what I try, the function (and the Syso) gets called immediately.

EDIT:
Ok, there is actually a problem with my Server or something... I copy-pasted now a code example from w3schools and it didn't work either... Tested with three browsers...
Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: first, I see an error, your ending bracket for the anzeigen function has a semi-colon. also, I'd take out the document.ready() function as that is irrelevant when you are counting on an event. do that and tell me you results!

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result... I don't get it... I tried so many different ways from stackoverflow and w3schools and none seem to work...

Comment: Just a question, i dont quite get the title, does your function will still be called when the button is clicked?

Comment: No, it gets called upon start, but nothing happens when I click the button...

Comment: the function is out of global scope because of the document.ready enclosure

Comment: EDIT: Ok, there is actually a problem with my server or something... I copy-pasted now a code example from w3schools and it didn't work either... Tested with three browsers... Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting JavaScript directly in the HTML, it is recommended to do something like this:

```
<button type="button" id="anzeigen">Notizen anzeigen</button>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#anzeigen').onclick(function() {
        $("#ausgabe").empty();
        <% System.out.println("test");%>
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/Notizblock/rest/" +     
                "notizblock/notizen",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(i, data1) {      
                        // Erstellt neues Element      
                        var p = $("<p>");      
                        // Zugriff aus JSON - Objekt      
                        p.append(data1.nnummer + " " + data1.tnummer);      
                        $("#ausgabe").append(p);     
                        });

                }
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result... I don't get it... I tried so many different ways from stackoverflow and w3schools and none seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the anonymous function you passed to the document.ready function will be invoked when the dom loads and fires the load event. With jQuery you wait for this event before interacting with dom elements.

You are assigning your action using the onclick property of the button, so you do not need to wait for this event.

**EDIT:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="anzeigen()">Notizen anzeigen</button>

<script>
  function anzeigen() {
    $("#ausgabe").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Notizblock/rest/" +     
        "notizblock/notizen",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i, data1) {      
              // Erstellt neues Element      
              var p = $("<p>");      
              // Zugriff aus JSON - Objekt      
              p.append(data1.nnummer + " " + data1.tnummer);      
              $("#ausgabe").append(p);     
          });
        }
    });
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: parens are required.

Comment: @dewd yes just double checked the documentation

Comment: @ToTom add a console.log to the anzeigen function body and comment out the rest of the anzeigen code. You'll see the function is only called when you press the button. You have a logic error somewhere else if it's still not working.

Comment: As I stated in the edit, the whole JS is not working... Not even when I paste an entire w3schools code...

Comment: @ToTom what does your html look like? Where did you include your script tag?

Comment: First under my code, then in a new dynamic web project, then static web project and finally on an editor file on my desktop... none worked...